# Yii relations issue

Tags: yii

I am having an issue with Yii relations.  I am using CGridView to display a table in a view.

I have the following relations in my model:

`'relationName' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, OtherModelName, link_id),`

When I call the value in my CGridView like the example below it works fine:

`'relationName.field_name',`

When I try to call the value inside an array like the example below:

`array('header'=>'tableHeaderName', 'value'=>'$data->relationName->field_name'),`

My page fails and I get the following error: `Trying to get property of non-object`

Any ideas or suggestions?  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Did you prefetch `relationName` before rendering the GridView (using `with`)? Are you sure that the related object is not null (is link_id not null)?

Comment: If my answer helped, I'd appreciate an up vote, thx!

Comment: Thanks acorncom that did the trick

Comment: Great, glad that helped.  Turns out I didn't mean an upvote, I meant "click the checkbox" :-)  That means that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this recently myself.  You'll need something like this:

```
array(
    'header'=>'tableHeaderName',
    'value'=>'(isset($data->relationName)) ? $data->relationName->field_name : null',
)
```

What happens is that Yii freaks out if the relation isn't always there.  So if you have any gaps in your data / relationships, then you run into problems.

Comment: What would you expect _Yii_ to do in this case to avoid the "freaking out" label? If you try to read from a null object, any programming language will "freak out".

Comment: Not a criticism of Yii, just an explanation of why he's seeing what he's seeing

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `relationName` has the same name with any of your DB table or not.